# Allow undeleting deleted questions for a short while if high rep for tag

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, vote-to-undelete

If you accept the current policy of disallowing an questioner from deleting their question if there is an upvoted answer.

High rep users get their high rep more often than not because people upvoting their answers. Checking my own answers ~80% have at least one upvote.

Assuming other users with a similar rep have a similar upvote to no vote ratio then the likelihood their answer would be upvoted is also 80%.

So in the end the only difference is timing. They wrote an answer likely to get an upvote. If they had hit submit a few minutes earlier they'd likely have gotten that upvote and that question would not be allowed to be deleted by the OP.

Yes, I get that the upvote might come later but the point is there is no real difference between a question that can't be deleted by the OP because of an upvoted answer and question with an answer being written by a high rep user. The odds are higher than not that answer would be upvoted and the question would be un-deletable.

Not allowing that high rep user to block the deletion if they started their answer within some reasonable time frame is basically arguing that all questions, even with an upvoted answer should be able to be deleted by the OP.

The difference appears to be

Sitation 1: Question with upvoted answer, probably 100%

Sitation 2: Question with answer being written by high rep user to have an a upvote: 80%

An 80% chance that the answer was found useful (received an upvote) seems like a win for the site.

If you disagree please state why you don't see those 2 situation as the same. Both lead to an question that can't be deleted by the OP. Timing seems to be the only difference.

---

**We don't allow deleting questions that have answers. So this is basically an extension of the same principle. If someone with a high rep is writing answer then an answer is in the process of existing. Why shouldn't that principle be upheld?**

This has happened to me more than once.

Someone, usually a student, asks a question that requires a fairly long answer. For some reason I'm in a generous mood, maybe because it's clear they are a student and are trying, have clearly shown effort, are confused and need some guidance.

I spend 1 to 2 hours literally, fixing their code and documenting why each fix is needed. This way it will hopefully be useful to others or at least their classmates.

And before I can get the answer up I find out the question has been deleted by the author. Maybe they found an answer somewhere else or got help from a friend or TA or they just got embarrassed and deleted their question or decided the help wasn't fast enough or whatever. My impression is they deleted it themselves.

But, in any case it feels awful to have put so much effort into an answer only to basically get punch to the face. It's discouraging from continuing to participate.

Would it be a reasonable idea to allow undeleting questions by people with immediate close level permissions for a certain amount of time?

---

As for the dupe link, that one is asking to warn the user. This one is not asking for a warn. This one is asking to extend the "can't delete a quesiton with an upvoted answer" policy to a logical conclusion.

Comment: If you believe your answer is important enough then just ask the question yourself.

Comment: That still doesn't explain why you think there is a different principle for a question with an answer submitted vs a question with an answer in the process of being written. Basically it sounds like I should just post an off topic placeholder answer "In the process of writing a long answer. This placeholder here to prevent poor UX  in S.O." and then go write my answer while i take all the downvotes on the off topic placeholder answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Please warn users before they delete a question if someone is writing an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322138/please-warn-users-before-they-delete-a-question-if-someone-is-writing-an-answer)

Comment: Adding a placeholder answer won't work because people will, as you mention, downvote it, and users can delete their own questions if the answers on it are not upvoted/accepted.

Comment: According yivi if I has 2 answers it can't be deleted so I can add 2 placeholders ;)

Comment: Could you explain why it is not an option to repost the question if it is a good one?

Comment: You say that "We don't allow deleting questions that have answers." Stack Overflow absolutely _does_ allow deleting questions that have answers, it just doesn't allow deleting questions that have _upvoted_ answers (or accepted, but that's kind of moot because the OP has unaccept powers).  It's just as frustrating, if not more, (and you don't get notified!) when the user deletes the question _after_ you post the answer.

Comment: Odds are ~80% my answer would have been upvoted as 80% of my current answers are upvoted. I'm going to guess that's similar for other high rep answerers.

Comment: @HansPassant, that's a pragmatic answer but irrelevant to my point. You could make that same argument for all questions, even those with upvoted answers. Let all questioners at anyitme delete their question for any reason and if you didn't like it then repost their question yourself. We don't do that. We don't let them delete if there is an upvoted answer. Odds are better than not a high-rep user's answer will be upvoted QED a user with high rep for the topic in question should be able to undelete if they've left an answer within some reasonble time of deletion

Comment: what @Hans suggested looks absolutely totally relevant here. Question asker is responsible for maintaining it - clarifying, improving, checking, voting, accepting and unaccepting answers etc etc. What Hans suggests is that you take care of all this because it is only you who is interested in that. What you want instead is to push all this weight on an original asker who already clearly indicated that they don't want to do all this work (and by the way were technically allowed by a system to drop it, so it's not a known abuse of running away after getting an answer)

Answer (score 8):

> Would it be a reasonable idea to allow undeleting questions by people with immediate close level permissions for a certain amount of time?

No, it wouldn't be reasonable.

If the question was deleted by the post author, they are within their rights. Users [can delete their questions if](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions):

- it has zero answers
- it has only one answer, but that answer has no upvotes and was not marked as accepted.
- has no bounties that were awarded to any answer that isn't already deleted

**The reputation of involved users never enters into it**. Only after an answer is posted and it receives upvotes (or more than one answer is posted) is the user blocked from deleting their question.

But of course, the community can still cast their own delete votes on the question.

And if the question was deleted by the community (moderator or regular votes), you need to work with the community. Edit the question so it's no longer deletion worthy. Cast undelete votes. Flag if you really must (e.g. it was deleted by a moderator).

And if you feel is really worth it, nothing stops you from posting your own version of the question, if you had already made all that effort and you believe a good, useful Q&A pair can be added to the repository based on the now deleted question.

As usual, the advice is to focus on higher-quality questions, where this kind of thing is less likely to happen.

Comment: The reputation of the user enters into it because they probably wouldn't be answering an off topic question since they have the rep to show they understand what an off topic question is, and, they are likely to get their answer upvoted since by rep they are likely to leave useful answers. So effectivetly there is no difference between early delete and late delete except early delete wastes the answerer's time and saps their motivation and denies people useful answers.

Comment: Personally, I have seen no evidence that a user with a lot of reputation is less likely to answer poor questions that would better be closed an deleted; compared any other user with less reputation.

Comment: But you're okay if a question is not deleted because an person of high rep left a answer that got upvoted even on a poor question. It still seems to come down to timing and not any principled argument. Poor questions are solved by closing. This is not about closing, it's about a user deleting their question.

Comment: I never said I was OK with anything of the sort.

Comment: And closing and deleting are inextricably related. Closure is an intermediate state for either fixing and reopening the question, or deleting it. And you are the one who brought closure into focus, by pointing out the "answering of off-topic questions". Off-topic questions need to be closed, until they are fixed.

Comment: My point with bringing up closing is that you claimed high rep users answer poor question. Poor questions are solved by voting to close and is entirely irrelavent here. If the question is not poor then wer'e back to the fact that there is no difference between disallowing deleting a question with a single upvoted answer and one which has an answer likely to be upvoted but submit has not yet been clicked. The only difference comes down to timing and nothing else.

Comment: I didn't claim anything like that. I just gave you advice. If this is happening to you with some frequency, it could be related to you hitting some poor targets. I was just advising you attempt choosing better quality ones. I never claimed high rep users answer poor questions.

Comment: (yivi) "Personally, I have seen no evidence that a user with a lot of reputation is less likely to answer poor questions". I guess i mis-understood.

Comment: Yes, you clearly misunderstood. I disagreed with your statement that users with more reputation are **less likely** to answer poor questions. I haven't seen evidence of that. I believe chances are more or less equal, and reputation is not a good predictor (of users choosing high quality questions to answer). Not only that, but you brought answering off-topic questions **before** I made that comment. So I'm not sure how could you "brought up closing" in response to that comment.

Comment: Interesting. I'd argue if nothing else, rep, more often than not means the user's answers get upvotes so people are finding their answers useful. If a high rep users is more likely to get upvotes because they leave useful answers then more likely, except for bad timing, their answer would have gotten the required upvote and the question could not be closed.

Comment: I believe you mean "could not be deleted", @gman. Questions with answers with upvotes can be closed.  Users of all reps get upvotes for answering crap questions all the time, because no one wants to do research. I've seen many people in my tags shoot up in rep very fast by simply shotgunning easy, duplicate questions with answers.

Comment: Yes I meant "deleted" not "closed". I'm sure what your point is though. If you want to see more questions deleted then you should be asking to let even questions with multiple or upvoted answser deleted. Otherwise my point still stands that the only difference between not allowing a question to be deleted by the poster and allowing it to be deleted when a high rep users is answering is timing. 4 out of 5 if my answers have a least 1 upvote so it's likely these ones would have as well. I don't care about gaining rep. I care about time being wasted

Answer (score 3):

I'm actually going to subvert my normal opinion of a suggestion like this and *agree* that, in principle...

- Users who delete their question within a certain amount of time can be frustrating.
- Users who don't respect the site's intentions or are already being hit with downvotes and comments which they <s>don't like</s> find impolite are more likely to delete their question just to get away from that mess.
- It is highly frustrating if I am attempting to answer a question when all of a sudden the question is deleted.

The problem is that I don't believe that *un*deleting the question is the right fix.  If the content is poorly received, I'm okay with it staying at the bottom of the lake; we don't need to raise sunken ships just because they *might* be full of gold.

The guiding wisdom is to focus on "higher quality" questions, but in reality...no one's asking those.  They're just asking questions which might be of some quality or use to someone else.  I've tried to identify "good" questions for years now, and the best I could say is that if the question doesn't read like a list of requirements, it has a chance of being passable.

That guiding wisdom isn't really useful to address the root issue:

## People think that deleting their question is a solution to its poor reception.

So fundamentally I'm agreeing with you that this is a frustration.  Your solution to the problem is not ideal, since - and I cannot stress this enough - deleted posts still count against people for question bans. With enough of that crap sinking to the bottom of lake, we'll have fewer question askers for it, and I don't see this as a bad thing.

Comment: An easy solution is to prevent the author of a question for 24 hours, from deleting their own question, if there are pending close or deletion votes.  This allows the community to do what they do best

Comment: @SecurityHound:  I disagree.  We've had people post proprietary code from their job here before that had to be "removed" (e.g. hidden from view) in a faster timeframe than that.  Additionally, there's no reason that an OP shouldn't be able to delete their question if they don't want to keep it.  The real tricky issue is that the deletion almost always happens in response to some feedback that an OP receives indicating that their question is poor.  Blanket "don't delete X for Y hours" isn't going to solve the "think about what you're asking before you hit Enter"-problem that is being dodged.

Comment: I am not saying prevent an author from deleting their question only delay it and only if the community is trying to deal with it.  Furthermore, deleted questions are only hidden, so that just makes proprietary code hidden.

Comment: @SecurityHound you are suggesting to block the most legitimate deletions - user gets feedback that post "does not show research", deletes the question, performs research (like 2-3 days) and undeletes/post brilliant question afterwards... Keeping not-so-good quality questions only serves to get OP more downvotes which does not make anyone happier...

Comment: " there's no reason that an OP shouldn't be able to delete their question if they don't want to keep it." There is a reason. User's aren't allowed to delete questions with upvoted answers. My answers (and I assume other high rep answerere) have ~80% upvote rate so odds are the answer would have been upvoted. So this all comes down to timing alone and no actual principled argument. If a high rep user is answering they're likely to post an answer others find worthy of an upvote which means the op has no right to delete.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - When a author submits a question they agree to a license that cannot be revoked.  There is a process to get information retracted from a question though